# Unable to understand the flow of angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new with anglarjs and I am working on ng-view example which is available [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView), actually the problem is that when I run application in firefox it show me only text in index.page, not shown any result related to angularjs.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
             Choose:
    <a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
    <a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: ch1</a> |
    <a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
    <a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: ch4</a> |
    <a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>
</div>
<pre>$location.path() = {{main.$location.path()}}</pre>
<pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{main.$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
<pre>$route.current.params = {{main.$route.current.params}}</pre>
<pre>$routeParams = {{main.$routeParams}}</pre>
```

**app.js**

The controller is define here.

```
var myApp = angular.module('ngviewExample',['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
            function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
                $routeProvider

                    .when('/Book/:bookId', {
                        templateUrl: 'book.html',
                        controller: 'BookCtrl',
                        controllerAs: 'book'
                      });
                $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                    enabled : true,
                    requireBase : false
                });             
        }])
            .controller('MainCtrl', ['$route', '$routeParams', '$location',
                function($route, $routeParams, $location) {
                  this.$route = $route;
                  this.$location = $location;
                  this.$routeParams = $routeParams;
              }])
            .controller('BookCtrl', ['$routeParams', function($routeParams) {
                this.name = "BookCtrl";
                this.params = $routeParams;
              }]);
```

All the angularjs files are loading fine but it's not showing any error in Firebug console. But when I debug this code I don't know why it go inside the following code  on accessing the url http://localhost:8383/TestingDirective/index.html

```
.when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: 'BookCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'book'
 });
```

Also shown in the snap-shot.
[image: Hello]

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here, only text of index.html page show on the page and nothing else.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you missed _div_ with `ng-view` attribute

Comment: To start, all of your `<pre>[...] {{main.<something>}}</pre>` tags are **outside** of your controller which you define `main`

Comment: Yes @Tom thank you for the requested information but it's still show the same behavior.